# Condition usage

Tags: bash, shell

I have a file with contents:

```
$> cat file
1
2
4
```

Now, I would like to use/run another script, if the differences between the numbers (subtraction) is larger than 1, else exit from the main script.

I tried to do this in the following way, but does not work:

```
less file \
| awk '\
    function abs(x){return (((x < 0.0) ? -x : x) + 0.0)}\
    BEGIN{i=1;}\
    {new=old;old=$1}\
    {if(abs($1-new)>1)i++;}
    END{if(i>1) print 1; else print 0;}' \
| while read i;do
 if (( ${i} ));then
 echo -n "Would you like to continue? [yes or no]: "
 read yno
   case ${yno} in   
       y )
           echo Continuing...
           ;;
       n )
           echo Exiting...
           ;;
       * )
           echo "Invalid input"
           ;;
   esac
 else echo Cont...
 fi
done
```

I would expect, that if ${i}==1, then I can make a decision, whether I want to continue or not.

Comment: Happy to help you resolve your problem if these solutions aren't helping, if you can clarify your intent by prompting "would you ...". Why can't you do the subtraction and allow exit codes to determine what happens outside of awk. You say  'but does not work:', please edit your question to show what error messages do you get, or indicate why do you say it's not working. It looks like it should work. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you wrote

> I would expect, that if ${i}==1,

Yes, but what if ${i} = "Error on input" or some other value, your statement needs to explicitly state your condition. Also using less to send a file to a pipe is not a standard situation, why not just pass in the filename to awk for processing, i.e.

```
awk '\
    function abs(x){return (((x < 0.0) ? -x : x) + 0.0)}\
    BEGIN{i=1;}\
    {new=old;old=$1}\
    {if(abs($1-new)>1)i++;}
    END{if(i>1) print 1; else print 0;}' file1 \
  | while read i;do
 if (( "${i}" == 1 ));then
 echo -n "Would you like to continue? [yes or no]: "
 read yno
 . . .
```

I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the only input is from less which is fully consumed by the awk script. The console is not available.

Would something like this be useful

```
i=$(awk 'function abs(x){return (((x < 0.0) ? -x : x) + 0.0)}BEGIN{i=1;}{new=old;old=$1}{if(abs($1-new)>1)i++;}END{if(i>1) print 1; else print 0;}' file)
if (( ${i} ));then
  echo -n "Would you like to continue? [yes or no]: "
  read yno
  case ${yno} in

    y )
       echo Continuing...
       ;;
    n )
       echo Exiting...
       ;;
    * )
       echo "Invalid input"
       ;;
  esac
else echo Cont...
fi
```